# Как спарсить страницу с javascript контентом?

Tags: php

На входе страница [Ссылка](https://allsocial.ru/communities)

Данные там формируются через javascript

Как их спарсить с помощью PHP? 
HTML DOM simple выдает голую страницу. Как получить результат выполнения скрипта на странице?

Comment: Зависит от того, насколько много делается яваскриптом. У меня есть рабочий (несколько лет назад) пример выделения телефона из объявления на Avito, там скрипт запускает простенький сервер на NodeJS и отправляет ему коды, получая результаты. Но не PHP.

Comment: А какие конкретно вам данные нужны? Сообщества с сайта?

Comment: именно. Ссылки на сообщества и кол-во подписчиков.

Answer (score 1):

Cтраницы, написанные на javascript, необходимо парсить браузерами. Посмотрите в сторону Selenium Webdriver с браузерами (Chrome, Firefox или другие)